# Docker Service not running on EC2 when launched in an AWS auto-scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I have a fresh Ubuntu image with just docker installed on it. I tested this image to make sure my docker container works and everything is working fine.
I create a golden AMI of this. I create a launch template and add below to the User Data.

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo docker pull command
sudo docker run command
```

My issue is that the command will not run. From the other testing I have done it seems like the docker service is not running when these commands are being executed. When I ssh on to the EC2 and check the docker service it is running. I can manually run the docker commands and it works.
Any idea why the docker service wouldn't run when it boots up with the autoscaling group?

I have tried adding a bash file and running that through the User Data but same thing.

I even added a sleep to see if the docker service would come up before running the commands but still the same thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're in control of building the golden image, why not just enable the docker service? `systemctl enable docker`

Comment: Thanks. I have already done that. When the autoscaling starts another instance the docker service does not start, so the docker commands wont work in the User Data. When I log into the instance though the docker service is started and I can run them. But this needs to be automated so it can be scaled.

Comment: How are you so sure that the docker service is not running when the user data is executed? When you log in, you see it running don't you? You can have two options, make a service and make it start after docker service. Or you can make a rule in eventbridge which calls a lambda(where you have your commands) upon launch successful.

Comment: I have an output log when running the docker command that says its not running. I tried to start the service before it runs but the ec2 freezes and you can not log into it anymore.